# MS Access: How to search a value on a table by clicking on a form record

Tags: ms-access, subform, continuous-forms

I'm pretty new to Access and coding in general and I've been working on a database that was filled with data extracted from SAP.

I have a query that works as a way to "summarize" the information of a bunch of records from some purchase orders, it does sum the total of each PO, it's date as well as other information. It does consolidate a variety of items related to the purchase order into a single record that is displayed in a continuous subform for easy analysis in this structure.

[MES_CORTE][SOLPED][PO][FirstMIGO][TOTALPOVALUE]

This way, the user can preview easily each purchase order, date, value and other relevant information. This query is also used to generate some reports.

However, I want to be able of opening the source table ([Registro_OC]) and search the related records by clicking a field on the subform for a detailed view and posibly to edit or enter new data. is it posible?

I've tried to code some macros but can't figure out how to reference the table fields related to the query fields that are on the form.

Also, it seems that Access doesn't allow to create subforms based on continous forms.

Any help and opinions are appreciated.

Comment: I am sure it's possible - most anything is with enough code. If you've tried something you should show attempted code. I don't use macros, only VBA. Odd thing about form/subform - I have one form that is set as Continuous and it has subforms. I am not able to build new form/subform to replicate.

Comment: I wasn't able to construct the macro with the tools access provide because I don't know how to reference the results on the field [PO] to the table and perform the search, I've tried a couple of things like more subforms but access doesn't allow me to use the continous form as a parent for other subform and honestly I've run out of ideas at this point, been three days stuck at this.

Comment: It is not clear what you need to do. Domain aggregate functions can pull data from table. But if you just need to open a form to a particular record, use something like; `DoCmd.OpenForm "formname", , ,"ID=" & Me.ID`